# Select all data from a second table where name is equal to a column value from first table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am working with a MySQL database wherein I have tables named as follows:

1. Users
2. 1247483647
3. 2147483613
4. 2047483641

The columns in `Users` are as follows:

1. userEmail
2. compId

How can I structure an SQL query which will:

a) Select the compId from the Users table where userEmail is equal to an email address provided via a mysqli prepared statement.
b) Then find the table with a table name which matches the compId and select all data from it?

I have so far tried as follows (to no avail):

```
    $sql = "
    SELECT * FROM table_name
    WHERE table_name =
    (SELECT compId
    FROM Users
    WHERE userEmail = ?)
    ";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a sample schema of 2 tables?

Comment: Dynamically choosing tables to query is usually a code smell. Why do those numerically-named tables exist?

Comment: @Chris They don't have to exist... I would love advice on a better way of structuring the database (especially if this is going to cause headaches later)...

Comment: This could obviously be done with two individual queries, but as Chris implies, this looks like a bad db design.

Comment: @jonhendrix, what do those tables contain?

Comment: Change the equal sign to the word `in`.

Comment: @Chris ok so the plan was that each table would be a new customer using what will be a multi-tenant application. Each table would contain customer data such as customer name, customer events, notes and comments made within the application (and more).

Comment: Chris' question asked another way: why do you have a table whose name is the primary key value of a row in another table? Why are you averse to having a second table called `something_static` that also has a column `compId`? I ask because it's important to me (in order to give advice) to work out why your mind envisaged this current solution in the first place..

Comment: Seems like you just want a `user_data` table, with the id number, and some other columns in.. just because three different companies out there use your software doesn't mean their address info has to be stored in 3 different tables.

Comment: @CaiusJard Hi - I'm not averse... just lacking in database design experience! Sounds like a better idea, as you have mentioned. If I were to go with that plan, would I need to use an SQL JOIN to relate the two? I thought that I would be saving myself trouble later on to have a separate table for each customer, and that it would be easier to manage at scale.

Comment: I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: Databases don't really care about things like that, tables with millions of rows etc.. it's only humans that try to do things for organisational reasons, such as putting all one customer's invoices in one shoe box, another customer invoices in another shoe box. What you need to see is that putting the customer id on each invoice conceptually does put them in a shoe box - `select * from invoices where custid = x` is equivalent to pulling shoe box x off the shelf.  yes you should absolutely just have a user data table, and you should join them. Index the user id column in the data table

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks for your advice Caius, it's much appreciated! I'm going to rethink.

Comment: If those are your table names, then there's really no hope.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to build the SQL string from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

```
select @querystring := CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', table_name)
    from information_schema.TABLES
where TABLE_NAME =
(SELECT 
    compId
 FROM 
    Users
 WHERE 
    userEmail = {?})

PREPARE statement from @querystring;
EXECUTE statement
```

I'm not the handiest with PHP but this works for me as long as you inject the userEmail in the {?} where I designated as a parameter.

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote? Did I miss the question? I'm trying to build up my reputation points I tested this query and I know it works as long as he substitutes the email address for {?} my question is, why did someone downvote my answer and his question? Is there something illegal about it? I'm new here so cut me some slack please.

Comment: Just specualating, but it might be because this answer kinda only helps the OP into deeper trouble further down the line. This is not only a site for answering people's every question/fulfilling their desires as demanded - it's also for learning and guidance as to how things should be done. Sometimes you have to balance up giving someone the answer they're looking for versus giving someone he answer they should be looking for. There are few hard and fast rules, don't take DVs personally, they're only worth -2 anyway and (by and large) the gamification of points acquiry is a sideshow to...

Comment: ..the true mission of the site, which is to help people - you can do that whether you're John Skeet or just starting out. Don't worry about it; you wrote an informative and detailed, thoughtful answer here. Keep applying the logic and your points trend will on average, rise rather than fall :) don't be afraid to rail against convention and point out an alternative way of doing things rather than answering the question as asked - I've done this recently, picked up a downvotes for it yet eventually had the OP comment that I was right and he did my suggestion.That's more a win than a few points:)

Comment: @Larry B thanks for answering - hope you get some points back for the accepted answer.